# How do I update a variable from javascript setInterval?

Tags: javascript

Say I have an object:

```
var myObj = function {
this.count = 0;
}

myObj.prototype {
   setCount : function() {
       var interval = setInterval(function() {
           this.count++;
       }, 500);
   }
}
```

The issue is count is always undefined within the setInterval so i can never increment the count variable within myObj to be something other than 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` changes depending on the function being called (and how it said function is called).

The anonymous function you pass to `setInterval` is a different function.

Copy the value to a non-magic variable first.

```
   setCount : function() {
       var that = this;
       var interval = setInterval(function() {
           that.count++;
       }, 500);
```

See [the `this` problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval#The_%27this%27_problem) in the documentation.

Comment: or use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval()` runs in the scope of the browser window, so `this.count` refers to `window.count` which does not exist.

Comment: How to grab a reference to the actual count I want and then increment it with setInterval? Or is there some other means besides setInterval?